# The probability that it "be" or "is" -- subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I am writing a scientific paper, and would like my diction to be as precise as possible. Regarding the subjunctive mood, I know the following is correct:

> "It is important that she **be** at home by 9 p.m.".

However:

> "The probability that temperature ***exceeds*** its historical maximum is large."

sounds to me better than

> "The probability that temperature ***exceed*** its historical maximum is large."

Which one is correct? Is it a matter of taste?

Comment: Only "exceeds" is OK here.

Comment: So is this not a subjunctive case here?

Comment: No - not every use of "that" needs the subjunctive (most don't). You could say "The probability of the temperature exceeding ..." which might be better depending on context (and would probably work well in situations where other languages might use a subjunctive).

Comment: I speak Portuguese as my native language, and this would be a subjunctive case there: "A probabilidade que a temperatura exceda seu máximo é alta". Interesting to think that this can change depending on the language.

Comment: *Pick a card. What is [the chance that it **be**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chance+that+it+be%2Cchance+that+it+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchance%20that%20it%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchance%20that%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0) an ace?* A few writers (mostly over a century ago) have used "subjunctive" ***be*** there, but the vast majority of us stick to Simple Present / Future *(...that it **is / will be** an ace)*. So I'd say it's "a matter of taste" - but if you're not a native speaker ***stick with the majority***.

Comment: The noun "probability" does not license a subjunctive clause as complement, so only your first example is correct.

Comment: In a scientific paper, you would want to sound authoritative in your tone and your supporting facts. Introducing the subjunctive risks sounding like conjecture or divination, not science. Just saying.

Comment: The subjunctive is generally used as a form of 'mandative' construction. A mandative construction tells the listener about some outcome which is considered desirable. These types of clause are complements of verbs such as "suggest/rule/order/insist/demand" or nouns such as "requirement/demand/recommendation" or adjectives such as "mandatory/imperative/ **important**". The reason the subjunctive is ok in example (1) is because "important" introduces an idea of a desired result. In contrast "probability" does not. It is entirely neutral about the outcome. A subjunctive is not possible here.

Comment: [For more information on mandative constructions see here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165857/i-demand-that-he-leave-or-leaves/165908#165908)

Comment: The law requires that the temperature in the classroom exceed 20 degrees C.

Comment: @GEdgar In your example, the subjunctive clause is complement of "require", not "exceed". A content clause in construction with "require" is always mandative.

Comment: Interesting question! Slight preference for "exceeds" to my ears, but I never knew why. By contemporary standards of science writing, I doubt it would bother most people. Seems like a similar construction to "the probability of the temperature exceeding X", but that would be adding length without a good reason.